# Any difference in downgrading a Windows admin account or creating a new standard user account?

Tags: user-accounts

I would like to downgrade my Windows 7 admin account to be a standard account, mostly for the added security benefits. I will have another admin account in case I need to install or update softwares.

Will I be better off (security wise) creating a new standard account instead of changing the type of my current admin account? And if so I would like to know why.

Comment: Makes no difference honestly.  As to the reason "why", there wouldn't be any difference, so why go to the extra work

Answer (score 0):

You won't be better off. Like mentioned, you'd only be adding more work for yourself.

The only reason I can fathom for creating a new user would be if the current one has been compromised, in which case the entire system could be compromised. So creating a new user would likely be a placebo for a solution.

If however your current user has been bogged down with lots of applications that start-up - **only for that user** - then creating a new one is a perfectly valid solution to that problem; seeing as it would require the least amount of work.

Answer (score -1):

The method I use at home and on the work network is to [rename the administrator account](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/change-built-in-administrator-account-name/) and create an additional standard account.

This will give you the separation you are looking for I believe.

Your best option no matter what you decide is to [enable user account control](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7).  This will help to prevent changes on your system that require administrative rights without your knowledge.

Comment: Renaming the default administrator account is a HUgE security problems the default account does not play by the same rules as a normal Administrator account.

Comment: Best to leave Administrator disabled since it cannot be enabled by a standard user, and requires WinRE, to enable it